# Programmatically hide an app from the LRU list

Tags: android, lru

I want to hide my app from the least recently used list (LRU) - the one that shows when you long press the home button.
Can it be done?
Thx.

**Edit**:
this app does it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBNwCZX8Cbo#t=99

so it seems that it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to the `Activity` tag in the Android Manifest, if you don't want your app to show up in the recent apps list:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude):

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded
>   from the list of recently used applications ("recent apps"). That is,
>   when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute
>   determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent
>   apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list; set
>   "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".

Comment: Thx, I will try and post result.

Comment: it did what I needed to do.

Comment: This works fine when the app is minimised or when the back button is pressed. But when the app is in the foreground and if I click on the recent button, the app will visible in the recent app list. How to handle this case?